# Update many sub documents where match using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a document of photos and on those photos I have sub array of arrComments. Each of the sub documents as a commenters profile picture (naturally there could be multiple comments on a single photo by the same user...)

When the user updates their profile picture, I want to update all of their profile picture references in all of the nested document comments for every picture.

I'm using PHP Mongodb driver for this btw. 
I tried this:

```
    ...etc...updateMany(
      array("arrComments.userOID"=>$userID), 
       array('$set'=>array('arrComments.$.userProfileImage'=>$arrFileName))
      );
```

but that only updates the first found comment within each picture... I need ALL comments by a user on ALL images to be updated.

Comment: why are you saving their profile pic to begin with... seems like a bad design to me...  Sorry just saying what is.

Comment: because mongo is a non-relational database system, I'm storing the data as I'm going to want it when I retrieved. This avoids me doing a kinda of left join on my query or a single query to go get the profile pics later. I'm willing to spend a bit more time on writing and saving my data (which happens in frequently) in order to save time on the massive number of reads later). I welcome your thoughts on this however.

Comment: My thoughts would be if you have to save it this way, and don't want to do it the other, why not save the profile picture in a way that you can overwrite it with the new one then you never have to change anything,  Of course I have no idea what you are saving, but it seems like there is a better way then having to update every instance of it.

Comment: I'm saving the picture within the comment because I show the comment creators picture along side their comment. Now, I could save a picture filenamed with the users ID, and then just load the profile picture by id, which would then mean I wouldn't have to update the database... but, I also have the users Full Name along side their comment, so when they update their profile, the fullname also needs to update. Same problem as the original question, just a different aspect to it.

Comment: Saving image data, man, I once did a mail order bride site and they had a 600GB database because of that.  They also compiled the pages into HTML, it was bad news....  Totally un-maintainable.

Comment: I think you're going about this problem the wrong way. You really shouldn't be storing your data like this. That being said, if you would like to continue in this direction, please check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E] for information regarding updating multiple matching array elements on a document. Note that MongoDB version 3.6 or later is required.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at that link. Curious, if mongo is a schemaless document based system where normalization is frowned upon, what would your strategy be to save data such as this? I'm thinking like, I have a resource table, and people can comment on resources, I would save the comments as sub documents as the resource, and with that document I would save the users photo and name so I don't have to go fetch it from somewhere else. Curious what you would do? Do you have a link or youtube video that would offer some guidance? Id rather do it right according to the industry then just because